# Change position of UITabBarButton in tab bar

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I increased my tab bar height via changing the frame of the `tabBar` in my custom `UITabBarController` class in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`.

However, the tab bar buttons do not remain vertically centered.

I tried to access the `UITabBarButton` views and set the frame manually, but it does not stay (has no effect). Not sure why the new frame is being reset/ignored. I also tried doing it in `viewDidAppear()` to no avail. Running out of ideas. Using Reveal app to edit it has no issues (not sure what they are doing to get it to stick).

Is there any way I can edit the frame of the button?

Comment: Share a screenshot

Comment: Thanks @RJ168 but I manage to figure it out, though the jump in position remains visible

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. It was a silly mistake of mine - forgot to remove a test set frame code. Either way, here is what I did and it has to be done in `viewDidAppear()` because that is where the button frames are properly updated and only then can we act on it (if anyone knows of a better way, please leave a comment!).

First of all I had to increase the height of the tab bar:

```
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        // Increase by 16 pt.
        let newTabBarHeight = tabBar.frame.size.height + 16

        var newFrame = tabBar.frame
        newFrame.size.height = newTabBarHeight
        newFrame.origin.y = view.frame.size.height - newTabBarHeight

        tabBar.frame = newFrame
    }
```

Then shift the buttons y-position:

```
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        let buttons = tabBar.subviews.filter { String(describing: type(of: $0)) == "UITabBarButton" }
        buttons.forEach {
            // Getting the button's superview height (probably can just take the tab bar `tabBar.frame.size.height` and remove the `if`).
            if let superviewHeight = $0.superview?.frame.height {
                // Accounted for the safe area insets for iPhone X and above.
                $0.center = CGPoint(x: $0.frame.midX, y: superviewHeight * 0.5 - ((appDelegate.window?.safeAreaInsets.bottom ?? 0) * 0.5))
            }
        }
    }
```

The above should hopefully work if the device rotated or for an iPad, but I did not test it out.

Here is alternate version using autolayout constraints for reference (since this is not so flexible if the bar changes width):

```
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        let buttons = tabBar.subviews.filter { String(describing: type(of: $0)) == "UITabBarButton" }
        buttons.forEach {
            $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                $0.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.centerYAnchor,
                                            constant: ((appDelegate.window?.safeAreaInsets.bottom ?? 0) * 0.5) : 0),
                $0.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: $0.frame.height),
                $0.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: $0.frame.width),
                $0.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.leadingAnchor, constant: $0.frame.minX)
            ])

    }
```

Unfortunately both will visibly show a jump in the buttons (moving from top to center) since it happens in `viewDidAppear()`, even for the autolayout constraints version. The alternative solution I believe would be to create our own tab bar though I have not done that before and am not sure what other implications that would have.

Hope this helps someone out as well.

Comment: Also note the key point here is using `center` instead of directly setting the `frame` or it will not work (not sure why, but I am guessing they perform some transformation which overrides the `frame` we set,  and the center point remains unchanged/valid).

Comment: This was a lifesaver! Thank you! Have a floating tab bar so the icon space from the bottom is still clickable when I'd rather the background was clickable. But this is good for now.